# grub rescue: “error: disk 'hd0' not found.”

Tags: grub2, kernel, grubrescue

The PC with Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS turn into grub rescue.

```
error: disk 'hd0' not found.
grub rescue> ls

grub rescue>
```

Like that, when I type `ls`, only a new line character outputted.
Any solutions?

Comment: Try booting from Live USB and check if you can access the disk from there. It might be that your disk is broken.